# How do I get socat OPENSSL-LISTE/CONNECT to use IPv4 only?

Tags: networking, socat

`socat` usually has separate command names for IPv4 and IPv6 variants (e.g., `TCP4-LISTEN:` vs `TCP6-LISTEN`). However, `OPENSSL-LISTEN/CONNECT` only seems to come in a generic variant. Is there a way to force it to use IPv4 only and not try IPv6?

Answer (score 1):

The correct option is actually `pf=ip4`